# multiple input values add or subtract one total

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have this code but is not working properly.

The idea is that every input has a value and sum or subtract its value from the total price depending if you click up or down.

Right now is just adding and adding and adding like crazy.

Thank you very much.

the JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".quantity").each(function(){
        $(this).change(function(){
            var quantity = ($(this).val());
            var ammount = ($(this).attr("data-price"));
            var price = $(this).closest(".bookSection").find(".item_price").html();
            var subtotal = ammount * quantity;
            var total = parseInt(subtotal) + parseInt(price);
            $(this).closest(".bookSection").find(".item_price").html(total);
        });
    });
});
```

here the example:
http://jsbin.com/tolequyobi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Every time a quantity changes, you are adding the subtotal to the price.  You are never subtracting anything from the price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to use the `.item_price` just calculate it from the start. If not you will need to store the old value to know if you need to add or subtract.

You can do something like this

```
$('.quantity').change(function(){ // check change on the inputs
    var total = 0; // set the total to 0
    $(this).parent().find('.quantity').each(function() { // loop on all the items thats in this block
        total += parseInt($(this).attr('data-price')) * parseInt($(this).val()); // add to the total their value
    });
    $(this).parent().find(".item_price").html(total); // and then add it to your html
});
```

Comment: Magic... Works perfect.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about recomputing the total from scratch whenever the quantity changes, instead of trying to keep a running total that you have to maintain?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var price = 0;
    $(".quantity").each(function(){
        $(this).change(function(){          
            var total = computeTotal($(this).closest(".bookSection"));
            $(this).closest(".bookSection").find(".item_price").html(total);
        });
    });
});

function computeTotal(bookSection){
  var total=0;
  bookSection.children('.quantity').each(function(item){
    total += $(this).val() * $(this).attr("data-price");
  });
  return total;
```

http://jsbin.com/rimubocijo/edit?html,js,output